# antlr error (infinite loop when RecognitionException happens)

Tags: java, antlr

I am using antlr for writing a lexer for a language.
After defining the grammar, antlr produced the java code for lexer class with the nextToken function in it. Each time I use this function, it returns a recognized token for me, but if it sees an undefined token it throws a `RecognitionException` exception and when it catches it, it throws another exception:

```
catch (RecognitionException e) {throw new TokenStreamRecognitionException(e);}
```

I have wrote a catch block to catch this exception and print something in the output, but the problem is after this, it seems that instead of just printing the error and going for the next token, it gets backs to to token before this, tests it again and comes back again to this undefined token, which ends to an endless loop, like:

```
ID      a_1
error occured at:   rowNum:1    colNum:8
line 1:8: unexpected char: '&'
ID      a_1
error occured at:   rowNum:1    colNum:8
line 1:8: unexpected char: '&'
ID      a_1
error occured at:   rowNum:1    colNum:8
line 1:8: unexpected char: '&'
...
```

How should I fix `nextToken` to only print the error and go for the rest of input program?

I searched the whole web but I could not fix the problem, I thought maybe you have come to this error before.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `OTHER` rule at the end of your lexer rules and let the rule match any character. This will then always match anything if the preceding lexer rules did not match. You then override `nextToken()` and inspect if it's a `OTHER` type or not:

```java
lexer grammar T;

@members {
  @Override
  public Token nextToken() {
    Token t = super.nextToken();
    if(t.getType() == OTHER) {
      // do something
    }
    return t;
  }
}

// other lexer rules

OTHER
 : .
 ;
```

Note that if you're using a combined grammar, `grammar T;`, then you should specifically define that the lexer member block like this:

```java
grammar T;

@lexer::members {
  @Override
  public Token nextToken() {
    Token t = super.nextToken();
    if(t.getType() == OTHER) {
      // do something
    }
    return t;
  }
}

...
```

Comment: Thanks Bart , yes I need to define the "OTHER" rule , but my main problem was that I had used "AntlrEclipse" plugin in my Eclipse to generate the java codes of my grammar and the "nextToken" function produced by it , seems to be my main problem  , when it came to miss match error , instead of stating the error and going to the nest token , it goes back in the input file and tries to examine this undefined token again , so it leads to an endless loop , So I think I have to use Antlr's "nextToken" function and override it as you said.